# put awesome font icons in c # code behind

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms

Currently I can measure the impressive font icons on my page with tabs from XAML code as follows:

```
<ContentPage.IconImageSource>
    <FontImageSource  FontFamily="{StaticResource Solid }" Glyph="&#xf108;" ></FontImageSource>
</ContentPage.IconImageSource>
```

That way I can already put icons in my applications, but I want to do it from the codebehind because that tabbed page will have to be created from certain actions and I did it in the following way:

```
 contenido.IconImageSource  = new ContentPage().IconImageSource {
    new FontImageSource().FontFamily = "\uf108";
};
```

but in the first "{" I get the error that says "I expected one ; "

**Update**

code App.xaml

```
<Application.Resources>
    <ResourceDictionary>
        <!--Global Styles-->
        <Color x:Key="NavigationPrimary">#2196F3</Color>
        <Style TargetType="NavigationPage">
            <Setter Property="BarBackgroundColor" Value="{StaticResource NavigationPrimary}" />
            <Setter Property="BarTextColor" Value="White" />
        </Style>

        <OnPlatform x:TypeArguments="x:String" 
            x:Key="Brands">
            <On Platform="Android" 
      Value="BrandsRegular.otf#Regular" />
        </OnPlatform>

        <OnPlatform x:TypeArguments="x:String" 
            x:Key="Regular">
            <On Platform="Android" 
      Value="FreeRegular.otf#Regular" />
        </OnPlatform>

        <OnPlatform x:TypeArguments="x:String" 
            x:Key="Solid">
            <On Platform="Android" 
      Value="FreeSolid.otf#Regular" />
        </OnPlatform>


    </ResourceDictionary>
</Application.Resources>
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You don't need to create a new ContentPage, just create a `FontImageSource` object and set the values accordingly then pass this object to the `IconImageSource` of your `contenido` Page.

Also, you will need to get the StaticResource from the App Resources Dictionary.

Something like this should work:

```
var solidFontFamily = Application.Current.Resources["Solid"] as OnPlatform<string>;
contenido.IconImageSource = new FontImageSource() { FontFamily = solidFontFamily, Glyph= "\uf108" };
```

Hope this helps.-

Comment: this line  "var solidFontFamily = Application.Current.Resources["Solid"] as string;" return null

Comment: How do you have defined the StaticResurce “Solid” in your App.xml Resources?

Comment: I Updated the post with the way have defined the StaticResurce “Solid”.

Comment: The code is right but you cast is wrong, you have to cast OnPlatform<string> instead of string, like this var solidFontFamily = Application.Current.Resources["Solid"] as OnPlatform<string>;

Comment: @MuhammadAdeelShoukat you're right. Thanks for the comment. I've just updated the code and it should work now.

Comment: No need, Glad to help.